# Scala casbah DSL queries

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm learning Scala and trying Mongo too. I'm creating a function that receives a `Map[String, Any]` as a parameter and I would like to return the proper `MongoDBObject` for it:

```
def parse(query: Map[String, Any]): MongoDBObject = {
  val result = query("operation") match {
    case "all" => query("field").toString $all query("value").asInstanceOf[List[String]]
    case "in" => query("field").toString $in query("value").asInstanceOf[List[String]]
    case "regex" => query("field").toString $regex query("value")
    case "eq" => query("field").toString $eq query("value")
    case "gt" => query("field").toString $gt query("value")
    case "gte" => query("field").toString $gte query("value")
    case "lt" => query("field").toString $lt query("value")
    case "lte" => query("field").toString $lte query("value")
    case "exists" => query("field").toString $exists query("value").asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    case "size" => query("field").toString $size query("value").asInstanceOf[Int]
    case "where" => $where(query("value").toString)
    case _ => throw new NotImplementedError("Unknown operation")
  }
}
```

I have some issues.

- the compiler says `$regex` is not a member of `String`. I don't know why.
- the compiler says that `Any` is not a valid query parameter. I suppose I should cast to int, string, date or any other valid Mongo type. Is there any way to fix this without reflection to solve wich type the value is?
- for the `$mod` operation I should give two numeric values as parameteres. Should I use a `List` as value for the map and get first and second items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains about `$regex` because it isn't finding a regex-able object on the right hand side to apply the conversion used to parse the `$regex` method--this is a problem you will run into with all of the following calls as well.

For the issue with `Any` (and also `$mod`), may I suggest a different approach? You have no type information with `Any`, so you can't really get around runtime casting (and I'm not sure how reflection would help you either.) You're not getting any of the benefits of a static type system that way. Here's a sketch of one way you could implement a method like this using a type hierarchy to enforce type safety:

```
sealed trait Query

case class All(field: String, value: List[String]) extends Query 
...
case class GreaterThan(field: String, value: Int) extends Query 
...
case class Mod(field: String, divisor: Int, remainder: Int) extends Query

def parse(q: Query): MongoDBObject = {
   q match {
      case All(f, v) => f $all v
      ...
      case GreaterThan(f, v) => f $gt v
      ...
      case Mod(f, d, r) => f $mod (d, r)
   }
}
```

Alternately, you could define an abstract execute method on `Query` and override it in each extending class instead of doing the `match` statement in `parse`. From there, you could abstract further using type parameters or generic types to allow, for example, `GreaterThan` to take any `Numeric` type.

Comment: Much better aproach. But still I will have to cast my Any to a type. I'm using this Map[String,Any] because I'm parsing a JSON using the scala native parsers. And it gives me a Map[String, Any], so I will have to cast this Any to the proper type. I thought about reflection to check wich type it is and return it with the proper cast.
About the $regex issue, I've used the tutorial in the docs that points me to use SBT, so I think it downloaded the latest jar. I've navigated through the jar and I've found the $regex function there... I have no idea why the compiler is complaining about this

Comment: If you have control over the JSON message format, you can use json4s (https://github.com/json4s/json4s) to both serialize & deserialize case classes easily. Even if you don't, using that library you could extract the query type and then deserialize accordingly.

Comment: Hi again... I'm trying the examples from their [website](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#extracting-values) and I'm always getting an error (Malformed class name)

Comment: I did it with Lift-json. But I still have a doubt
In a case like $eq that supports multiple Types, how can I solve the problem? I can't have two classes with the same name. So I can't have a Eq(field:String, value: Int) and a Eq(field:string, value:String)

Comment: The classes could be named anything you want. If you're feeling especially advanced, you might look at how the casbah library writers handled this issue, since it's open source: https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-query/src/main/scala/CoreOperators.scala#L142 https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-query/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala#L182