# The MongoDB Scala binding Casbah query DSL acts strangely with $regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, scala, casbah

I have some code attempting to use $regex in a query:

```
val mongoClient = MongoClient()  // connect locally
val db = mongoClient("testdb")
val gridfs = GridFS(db)

val x = gridfs.files("filename" $regex "^[a-zA-Z]+\\/.+")
x.foreach(println)
```

The idea is to print all items in a directory. But when compiling it complains:

> value $regex is not a member of String

But when I use $eq it seems to be fine:

```
val x = gridfs.files("filename" $eq "index.html")
```

A question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862587/scala-casbah-dsl-queries) that said:

> It complains about $regex because it isn't finding a regex-able object on the right hand side to apply the conversion used to parse the $regex method--this is a problem you will run into with all of the following calls as well.

I am not sure if this is actually valid.

Further confusion lies [$regex being defined in a trait](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.regexOp) without any implicit.

I am very new to Scala, the documentation is confusing at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the following query

```
("filename" -> "/name/i".r) or "filename" $regex "/name/i"
```

this will render

```
{ "name": { "$regex" : "/name/i" } }
```

instead of

```
{ "name" : { "$regex" : /name/i } }
```

Casbah will recognize the type of the second argument and make the query appropriate. If you send pattern instead of regex like the following:

```
"filename" -> java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("name", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

you will get what you want:

```
{ "filename" -> { "$regex" : "name", "$options" : "-i" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala native regexes in your query eg:

```
val x = gridfs.files("filename" $eq "^[a-zA-Z]+\\/.+".r)
```

It seems that `$regex` for some reason wasn't added to the core DSL implicit converters and I'll fix that in Casbah 2.7 ([SCALA-142](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SCALA-142))